# Future simple tense + before + present simple tense

Tags: present-simple, future

• Is the following sentence **formation/structure correct?**
(I found it in a book).

**`John will come before Adam comes.`**

• What is the **simplified meaning** of this sentence ?

Comment: Note that in a construction like this where the same verb occurs twice, it is normal to replace the second  verb with a do- verb. for example "John will come before Adam does"

Answer (score 0):

This means that in the future, Adam and John will both come (probably meaning they will arrive somewhere), but that John will come first. This pattern is a way of specifying when the future tense event will happen.

If it makes more sense, the sentence can also be flipped around to be *"Before Adam comes, John will come."* and have the same basic meaning.

### Other Examples

Here are some other examples of the same pattern:

> I will win before the game is over.

This means that I will win the game, and I will do that before the game ends.

> Will you eat before you leave the house?

This is framed as a question but the pattern is the same. It is saying that you will leave the house and asking whether you will eat first.

And some more examples:

> He will study before he takes the exam.

> I will clean before I have guests over.

> My friends will call me before they go to the beach.

> I will finish my homework before I play video games.

Comment: Is it a special use of 'present simple' to signify a future meaning?

Comment: In this case, the fact that the present tense actually means a future event can be logically understood. If event A is happening before event B and event A is happening in the future, then event B must be happening in the future too.

Comment: You could make the second part of any of these sentences into the future tense and it would still be grammatically correct. For example: "I will clean before I will have guests over." This means the same exact thing. But because they mean the same thing, using future tense in the second part is redundant and so is eliminated.